# Chai / Expect - how to work while developing? Seems really hard to go from expect().to.throw to logging the error

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I have this code

```
expect(function() {
   //some error
}).to.throw(Error);
```

How do I *easily* go from this to logging the error right here in the test?

Do I really have to type try/catch and console.log? Doesn't that go against the fact that I will need to remove them eventually for the test to pass?

Comment: yeah, don't explain the downvotes

Comment: I would down vote this myself, but since others have and did not explain themselves, I'll just give you my two cents worth. When you write a test with the expectation to throw an error it's because the scenario which you're testing actually throws an error. If, on the other hand, the unit under test catches the error and logs something to the console, then you should be testing for that scenario. The idea is that your hit tests should check for the resulting behavior of your code, what ever that behaviour may be, under a particular set of circumstances.

Comment: Don't people tune the code as they develop the test? For example in the above error, it was expecting a specific error type and wasn't getting it. Just wanted to log the value `expect` was getting.

Comment: Sure, if your code is not working as "expected". Can you post the code your trying to test, along with the actual test? What is the code supposed to do in the particular scenario you're testing? If it's suposed to throw an error then you test for that. If its supposed to log to the console, then you test for that. If your tests are well written to begin with, they will pass if your code performs as expected or fail otherwise.

Comment: I wanted the test pass a specific condition and it wasn't... It's not a development question, it's a development-process question. The question is how to get the error value from expect. If I say `expect().to.throw()`, how can I reference the error itself?

Comment: It's kind of hard to answer your questions with generic descriptions. Maybe if you post the actual function/method under test and the actual test we have be of more help.

Comment: If you catch the error yourself, `expect().to.throw()` is meaningless, if you don't, there's no way to get the error object in the test itself. It's not a code example I can give, because I don't know how to do it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79881/discussion-between-jme-and-madd0g).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Chai `.toThrow()` matcher can be used to ways:

1. to check of the error throws is of a particular instance

   ```
   expect(function() {
     throw SyntaxError('sample error message');
   }).to.throw(SyntaxError);
   ```
2. to check text of the error message

   ```
   expect(function() {
     throw SyntaxError('sample error message');
   }).to.throw(/sample error message/);
   ```

If this doesn't suite your use-case, you can always `try/catch` and inspect/make assertions on the object of the caught error:

```
try {
  throw SyntaxError('sample error message');
} catch(e) {
  expect(e.message).to.equal('sample error message');
}
```

Comment: It's too bad there's no way to go from testing the error to getting the error instance without adding try/catch.

Comment: Just because there're no matchers right now with Chai it doesn't mean we can't create them. Chai is extensible. If I actually knew your intentions I could develop a Chai plugin with matchers that could serve your use-cases. Unfortunately, your question has been so vague and cryptic that, o this point, I still have no idea what your specific need/use-case is.